# Using Powershell, how do I iterate through all "Network Locations" on a user's computer at login?

Tags: powershell, authentication

I am replacing a file server that has numerous files shares. Our users have "Network Locations" to this and other file servers. Searching the internet I found enough information to allow me to create a PowerShell script to create "Network Locations" to the new file server but I have not found the information I need to find and delete "Network Locations" to the old server. Here is my question...

How do I iterate through all the existing "Network Locations" on a user's computer to identify ones pointing to the old server and delete them?  Below is an example of three "Network Locations" on a users computer. The entries I need to delete are any that point to file server "fs02".

Sample File Shares of "Network Locations":

```
\\fs01\share001

\\fs02\share002

\\fs03\share003
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
Chuck R.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - note how the ``\\`` in your paths renders as just ``\``

Comment: take a look at the smb cmdlets. for instance, this >>> `Get-Help get*smb*map*` <<< seems interesting.

Comment: Thank you Lee_Dailey, I will check it out.